# How to catch basePath from model in zend framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to catch base path like view. In view base path easy get by using helper function like `$this->basePath();` I want to get basepath value from model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add getter/setter to your Model:

TestModel.php

```
<?php
class TestModel   
{
    protected $_basePath;

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public function setBasePath($path)
    {
        $this->_basePath = $path;
    }
}
```

Now inject this when you instantiate your model

Service Manager Config:

```
'factories' => array(
    'Application\Model\TestModel' => function($sm){
        $model= new \Application\Model\TestModel();
        // Just grab what we want from the view helper
        $helper = $sm->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('basePath');
        $path = $helper(); // or $helper('filenamehere') for added file path
        // Alternatively you can just use the request to get the path
        //$path = $sm->get('Request')->getBasePath();

        $model->setBasePath($path);

        return $model;
    },
```

If you have the Service manager / Service Locator available inside your model you could just directly get the value inside your model using one of the methods above.

```
 $path = $serviceManager->get('Request')->getBasePath();
```

If you look at how the ViewHelper is instantiated you see it first checks the config:

```
$config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
if (isset($config['view_manager']) && isset($config['view_manager']['base_path'])) {
     $basePath = $config['view_manager']['base_path'];
} 
else {
    $basePath = $serviceLocator->get('Request')->getBasePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do in model, but in controller you can do this :

```
<?php
   $myUrl =  $this->url()->fromRoute('home');
```

Comment: This may much useful in controller $url= $this->getRequest()->getUri(); then catch each value like this $schema = $url->getScheme(),->getHost() etc. But I want to get basePath directly from Model Class.